# How to get device longitude and latitude programmatically in Android?

Tags: android

I don't know to how to get the latitude and longitude of device by programmatically? If you can provide some code snippet to get the latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2):

You ask the [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

Comment: And if the OP is looking for comprehensive sample code, this does a good job: http://code.google.com/p/foursquared/source/browse/main/src/com/joelapenna/foursquared/location/BestLocationListener.java

Comment: Hi will, But i dont know how to get the longtitude and latitude using LocationManager.and i m using emultor to test the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at providing mock location data to emulator:

http://d.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html